# Why does the color set by vertex and fragment shaders in three js depend on the camera position of the scene?

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader, react-three-fiber

I made 1000 points and gave them coordinates to create a ring shape. I then gave a shader material to the points and pointed to the vertex and fragment shaders.

Vertex Shader:

```
const vertexShader = `
uniform float uTime;
uniform float uRadius;

varying vec3 vColor;
varying float vDistance;

void main() {

  vDistance = distance(position, vec3(0.0));

  // Do Not Touch
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
  gl_PointSize = 5.0;
}

`

export default vertexShader
```

Fragment Shader:

```
const fragmentShader = `
uniform float uDistance[1000];
uniform float uResolutionWidth;
uniform float uResolutionHeight;

varying float vDistance;

  void main() {

    vec2 resolution = vec2(uResolutionWidth, uResolutionHeight);

    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/resolution;
    
    float pct = distance(st, vec2(1.0));

    vec3 color = vec3(mix(vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), pct));

    gl_FragColor = vec4( color, 1.0 );
  }

`

export default fragmentShader
```

What I had wanted to do was assign a color to each point based on its distance to the origin. However I realized what I did is assign a color based on the pointer distance to the camera, or at least it's what its looking like

[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT:

I tried to pass along a varying vDistance like so

```
varying vec3 vRealPosition;

void main() {

  vDistance = distance(position, vec3(0.0));
  vColor = mix(vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), vDistance);
  vRealPosition = position;

  // Do Not Touch
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
  gl_PointSize = 5.0;
}
```

But when I used it in fragment shader all points are just blue

```
varying vec3 vRealPosition;

void main() {

    vec2 resolution = vec2(uResolutionWidth, uResolutionHeight);

    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/resolution;
    
    float pct = distance(vRealPosition, vec3(0.0));

    vec3 color = vec3(mix(vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), pct));

    gl_FragColor = vec4( vColor, 1.0 );
  }
```

Comment: "*What I had wanted to do was assign a color to each point based on its distance to the origin.*" I don't see anything here involving "the origin". What space do you expect this origin to be in? `gl_FragCoord` is in window-space.

Comment: Idk what you mean, but I mean by the origin of the scene, so I would guess position [0,0,0]

Comment: @NicolBolas I tried passing along real world positions from the vertex shader, but all the points are just blue now, do i have to convert `gl_FragCoords` to the world position values?

Comment: "*do i have to convert gl_FragCoords to the world position values?*" That's like asking if adding 3 feet to 5 meters means 8 feet or 8 meters. Of course all of your positions have to be in the same coordinate system. If that's not the case, none of the math makes any kind of sense. Personally, I don't see a reason why you're doing this in the FS anyway.

Comment: @NicolBolas Im new to both, I thought the FS is where colors are assigned and the VS the positions. The points by default are a square, to convert them to circles I was using FragColor with a vec4. From the VS I cant use FragColor but I can use the color attribute which is a vec3. Are you saying I don't need the FS at all and I can do everything using just the VS?